# Will Dart scripts run natively in the browser?

Tags: html, dart

The Dart language looks like a very nice technology to build web applications for the web. For me it seems that there are no browsers available (yet?) which can run Dart scripts natively. Although there's a description on Dart's site about how to embed such scripts into HTML. I understand that for now i have to "compile" Dart scripts to Javascript. But will this change in the future or the language is designed to be translated to other script standards similar to Haxe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**As of March 25 of 2015, the offical answer is: no**.

Source: [Dart for the Entire Web](http://news.dartlang.org/2015/03/dart-for-entire-web.html)

Google dropped the integration plan of the Dart VM into Chrome in favor of optimizing the Javascript compilation. Dartium is still accessible for development purposes.

Comment: This was so disappointing. There are few things more frustrating than debugging through generated code. That's what pushed me away from CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 27):

This is speculation, but I guess that Chrome will likely support dart natively in the future. It will mean that Chrome will be able to outperform other browsers that don't have the native support.

**Update:** There's a hint from [The Official Google Code Blog](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/10/dart-language-for-structured-web.html) that it might be coming:

> The Dart VM is not currently integrated in Chrome but we plan to explore this option.

**Update 2:** It looks like I was right! Here's some [recent news](http://thenextweb.com/dd/2012/10/16/google-releases-new-dart-sdk-and-teases-native-browser-support-in-special-chromium-build/):

> Additionally, and perhaps most importantly, Google is releasing Dartium, a Chromium build with native Dart support.
>
> It’s more than likely that Dartium is part of a series of steps that Google will be taking to launch native support in Chrome — greatly improving the usefulness of Dart. Bringing native support into other browsers like Firefox and IE, on the other hand, will be quite the challenge.

**Update 3**: Since I posted this answer, Microsoft have released [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) which is a competing technology. I'd say it's unlikely that Microsoft have any intention of integrating Dart into Internet Explorer as they would probably prefer people to use TypeScript rather than Dart.

Comment: I was waiting for Dart to become available in the developer channel of Chrome. I'm a bit disappointed that their browser don't have a native runtime environment for Dart yet. But hopefully this will change in the future. I'm also waiting for a decent IDE or at least a plugin for current IDEs.

Comment: Dart Editor and the Dart plugin for Eclipse are very decent.

Comment: "Mozilla's Brendan Eich, who developed the JavaScript language, stated:  I guarantee you that Apple and Microsoft (and Opera and Mozilla, but the first two are enough) will never embed the Dart VM. So 'Works best in Chrome' and even 'Works only in Chrome' are new norms promulgated intentionally by Google. We see more of this fragmentation every day. As a user of Chrome and Firefox (and Safari), I find it painful to experience, never mind the political bad taste."  And I would add to that, that the language itself sucks when compared to both AS3 and JavaScript anyway.

Comment: Here is a [good comparison of typescript and dart](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/167070/differences-between-typescript-and-dart). Also, I believe it is [Dart's performance](http://www.dartlang.org/performance/) in addition to the sanity brought to massive applications, that will give it traction in the long run, in contrast to the quirks and annoyances which @triynko mentioned.

Comment: It doesn't matter really... javascript that is generated from dart runs faster than javascript. http://news.dartlang.org/2013/03/why-dart2js-produces-faster-javascript.html `The dart2js compiler, which converts Dart to JavaScript, now produces smaller and faster code thanks to its global type inferencer. By analyzing the entire program, the compiler can eliminate bailouts and redundant checks, resulting in code that runs faster on modern JavaScript engines.`

Comment: i am from future and dart still doesn't run in chrome as is.

Comment: The official answer is "No". Could you update it? ref: https://dart.dev/resources/faq#:~:text=has%20web%20support-,Q.,run%20across%20the%20modern%20web.

Answer (score 18):

The official answer is Yes, Dart will run natively in Chrome. The branch of Chrome, affectionately called Dartium, is now available as source, and binaries will be released soon. More information on how to get and build the source: http://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/BuildingDartium

Comment: I know it's hard to tell etas but is there any news when we can expect integration of the Dart runtime into Chrome? As far as i remember GC engine and reference counting need to be changed so it can both server the JS and Dart VMs from the same browser process.

Comment: The official answer is "No". Could you update it? ref: https://dart.dev/resources/faq#:~:text=has%20web%20support-,Q.,run%20across%20the%20modern%20web.

Answer (score 8):

Eventually, yes. The proposed MIME type + usage looks like this:

```
<script type="application/dart">
  main() {
    Element element = document.getElementById('message');
    element.innerHTML = 'Hello from Dart';
  }     
</script>
```

(That example looks like JavaScript, but don't be fooled!)

Comment: I don't understand, If it looks like JavaScript, then what has changed? What's the good part?